# Models works accept support vector machine SVM and Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: python

I am using PYCharm environment python 3.7.4 
I have imported CSV files to train models and predict the output. I have different Algorithms as follow:

1- Gaussian
2-Logistic regression
3-KNN
4-Decision tree
5-SVM
6-Linear discrimination

Prediction models working fine except support vector machine SVM and Linear Discriminant Analysis which they show an error (displayed below). Taking the fact when I run them on Jupiter Anaconda environment they work fine.

The picture shows the different algorithms and output

[image]

Libraries:

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import seaborn as sb
import warnings
```

Data Type: int

Data shape:

```
X.shape (637, 5)
Y.shape (637,)
```

support vector machine SVM Error:

_______________________ERROR__________________________________
        Traceback (most recent call last): , line 1320, in pushButton_8_handler
         ax1 = sns.distplot(Y_predict)

_______________________CODE__________________________________
         def plot_distribution(inp):
                    plt.figure()
                    ax = sns.distplot(inp)
                    plt.axvline(np.mean(inp), color="k", linestyle="dashed", linewidth=5)
                    *, max* = plt.ylim()
                    plt.text(
                        inp.mean() + inp.mean() / 10,
                        max_ - max_ / 10,
                        "Mean: {:.2f}".format(inp.mean()),
                    )
                    return plt.figure
                print( np.mean(Y_test) )
                print( np.mean(Y_predict) )

```
    #________________________Dist Predict Vs. Test and Means value_________________________
            plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
            o=np.mean(Y_test)
            tt=np.mean(Y_train)
            ax1 = sns.distplot(Y_predict)
            ax2 = sns.distplot(Y_test)
            RR1=('Mean:', tt)
            RR2=('Mean:', o)
            plt.axvline(np.mean(Y_predict), color='b', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=5,label=RR1)
            plt.axvline(np.mean(Y_test), color='orange', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=5,label=RR2)
            plt.legend()
            plt.savefig('SVM.png')
```

Linear Discriminant Analysis Error:

```
_______________________ERROR__________________________________    
        AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

        The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

        Traceback (most recent call last): , line 829, in pushButton_4_handler
            Classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)

_______________________CODE__________________________________

        #____________LinearDiscriminantAnalysis____________________

            def pushButton_4_handler(self):
                from PIL import Image

                f = ('Test.csv')
                data = pd.read_csv(f)
                data = data.dropna()
                X = data.drop('DrainStatnumout', axis='columns')
                Y = data['DrainStatnumout']
                data.Failuer = data.Failuer.astype(int)
                print(data)

                X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20)
                Classifier = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
                Classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
                Y_predict = Classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should improve your question to allow us to help you, add more error information, libraries you are using, shape and type of data...